# Firebase Android studio Notifications

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, открываю в Android Studio Firebase и не вижу там пункт Notifications, хотя вроде должен быть там, можете подсказать почему нет его? Версия 3.0 студии.

Comment: там есть пункт Cloud Messaging